# be ease for when

Tags: prepositions

[The Wonderful Wizard of Oz - 12. The Search for the Wicked Witch](https://www.pagebypagebooks.com/L_Frank_Baum/The_Wonderful_Wizard_of_Oz/12_The_Search_for_the_Wicked_Witch_p1.html)

> "How, then, are we to find her?" inquired the girl.
>
> "That will be easy," replied the man, "**for** when she knows you are in
>   the country of the Winkies she will find you, and make you all her
>   slaves."

Is this "for" a part of "be easy for", or it just means "because"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **for** means "because" here.

"That will be easy," replied the man, "*because* when she knows you are in the country of the Winkies she will find you, and make you all her slaves."